# JavaScript Determine if dynamically named function exists

Tags: javascript

How can I check if a *dynamically* named object or function exists?

In example:

```
var str = 'test';
var obj_str = 'Page_'+str;

function Page_test(){

}

if(typeof obj_str() == 'function') alert('ok');
else alert('error');
```

Then how can I then call the Object?

In example:

```
var tst = obj_str();
```

Comment: When you're calling a function based on anything specific to the page (e.g. the title or URL) then you're referencing a *dynamic* function, string or object. This is a great method of having something such as subjective form validation when some forms require validation though not all forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a global by its name by writing `window[obj_str]`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/8Nr4G/).

Comment: if the object exists.. how can I den use it? call it?

Comment: By writing `window[obj_str]`.  For example: `var result = window[obj_str]();`.

Comment: here I get 'undefined'... var Obj = window['Page_test']; alert(Obj());

Comment: @clarkk: That's because your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: it does return something.. "Obj is not defined"

Comment: function Page_test(){
 return 'hahha';
}

Comment: Wrong.  Your function has no `return` statement.  Ergo, it doesn't return anything.  When you call it (by writing `Obj` **`()`**), it doesn't give back a value.

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but don't try to *call* `obj_str` (it's just a string, it's not callable); instead, use it to look up the property on `window` (since all global functions and global variables are properties of `window`):

```
if(typeof window[obj_str] == 'function') alert('ok');
//               ^-- No (), and use `window`
else alert('error');
```

If you don't care that it's specifically a *function*:

```
if (obj_str in window) alert('ok');
else alert('error');
```

The `in` operator checks to see if a given string matches a property name in the given object (in this case, if the contents of `obj_str` are a property in `window`).

Answer (score 1):

Your example is right, except drop the parenthesis after `obj_str()`:

```
if(typeof obj_str != 'undefined') alert('ok');
else alert('error');
```

This is a bit more correct than `window[obj_str]` because obj_str may be defined in a local closure, or if you have nested closures, in a containing closure but not in window itself.

Answer (score 0):

if you run your code in browser, just access global object by `window`, your code may like this:

```
if (typeof window[obj_str] === 'string') {
    alert('ok');
}
```

otherwise, you should gain access to global object:

```
var global = function() { return this; }() || (1,eval)('this');
if (typeof global[obj_str] === 'stribg
```