# Determine if statically named JavaScript function exists to prevent errors

Tags: javascript, function

I have a script on my website that calls a *statically* named function when called:

```
childLoad();
```

The `childLoad()` function is not always defined though it is always called. How can I prevent the script from calling this function if it does not exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [does an Object/function exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848700/does-an-object-function-exists)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair No, technically each question is the same general scenario however the context is that this question is in regards to a *statically* named function that never changes while the question you referenced was inquiring about a *dynamically* named function.

Answer (score 57):

```
if ( typeof childLoad == 'function' ) { 
    childLoad(); 
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use short circuit evaluation:

```
childLoad && childLoad();
```

---

EDIT

```
('childLoad' in this) && childLoad && childLoad();
```

This will make sure `childLoad` can be referenced, makes sure it's not undefined, then call the function. It doesn't check to make sure it is a function, but I personally feel that is not needed.

NOTE: `this` might not be the context you are referring to if you are using `call` or `apply`. It really depends on the rest of your code.

Comment: Nice and short, but will fail if there is, say, a variable called childLoad (but not a function called childLoad).

Comment: Well, if `childLoad` is not **defined** (e.g. it wasn't previously declared), this will produce a `ReferenceError`, since the identifier doesn't exist on the scope chain...

Comment: @JacobM, will 100% true, it should fail as it's a function. So there would be large issues.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Yeah, IMO `typeof` is the way to go, you make sure the identifier is resolvable, and that its value it's actually *"callable"*... Also, we have to note that *callable* means a little bit more than just *"function"*, there are some implementations for example that have callable `RegExp` objects, and `typeof` recognize them as `"function"`s, and there are some *host objects* in some environments, which are in fact *callable*, but `typeof` returns just `"object"` (e.g. `window.alert` in IE<=8).

Answer (score 6):

```
if(typeof childLoad == 'function') {   
  childLoad();   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check:

```
if (childLoad)
    childLoad()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could surround it in a try catch!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
/* yourfunction */
if(typeof yourfunction == 'function') {   
  yourfunction();   
}
function yourfunction(){
  //function code
}
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.