# JQuery check if variable is function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I check if the return variable is a function?

```js
var testController = function() {
  alert('123');
}

$(function() {
  $('[mfour]').each(function(e, t) {
    var a = $(t).attr('mfour');
    console.log($.isFunction(testController));
    console.log($.isFunction(a));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div mfour="testController">asd</div>
```

Notice that on first `console.log` returns TRUE when the function name is hard-coded while on the second `console.log` if the variable is being evaluated returns FALSE.

It is kind of weird because `var a` returns `testController`.

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqmwjsp2).

My goal here is to run certain functions base on the mfour attribute. So in the example above, testController will run testController function.

Comment: a html attribute is always a string and not a function

Comment: `attr()` will always return a string, never a function. The fact that it might be the *name* of a function is irrelevant.

Comment: I guess you would rather want something like http://stackoverflow.com/q/5848700/218196 .

Comment: You really should put all functions in an object and then just access it with `myObj[funcName]`.

Comment: Use `typeof yourVar === "function"` instead of `$.isFunction()`, it's faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, to get a reference to the `testFunction` if it is in scope, you can use `eval`. Yes, I said it, `eval`, so you have to know that the string could be manipulated by the user to run malicious code if you don't sanitize it for function names;

```js
var testController = function() {
  alert('123');
}

$(function() {
  $('[mfour]').each(function(e, t) {
    var a = eval($(t).attr('mfour'));
    console.log($.isFunction(testController));
    console.log($.isFunction(a));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div mfour="testController">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `window[varname]` - assuming the function is in global scope

like this

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/uu8qrqfL/)

```js
var testController = function() {
    alert('123');
}

$(function() {
    $('[mfour]').each(function(e, t) {
        var a = $(t).attr('mfour');
        console.log($.isFunction(testController));
        console.log($.isFunction(window[a]));
        console.log(typeof window[a] === "function");
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div mfour="testController">Hello</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work either [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/nqmwjsp2/2/)

Comment: As I said: "assuming the function is in global scope" yours is in the onload

Comment: @user1781041: The function in your example is not global.

Comment: Here is a fixed fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/uu8qrqfL/

Comment: @user1781041 And as explained in other comments, all you have is a string, if it's in the global scope, you can access it, if it's private, you may not have access to it.

Comment: @mplungjan, your fiddle is working but mine is not (http://jsfiddle.net/nqmwjsp2/3/). I just copy-pasted yours to mine. Though I notice that yours is set to "No wrap - in <head>" while mine is "onLoad". Any difference between the two?

Comment: Yes THAT. The scope is global in mine in yours it is the jquery load scope

Answer (score 1):

To check if the variable is a function just add a check

```
typeof variableName
```

It will return the type of variable.

Dude..

If possible, add your function to an object. Like below

```
var obj = {
    testController: function(){
       alert('123');
    }
};

    $(function() {
        $('[mfour]').each(function(e, t) {
            var a = $(t).attr('mfour');
            console.log($.isFunction(obj[a]));
        })
    });
```

Comment: Maybe `$.isFunction(obj[a])`?